# What is the proper documentation for using django channels on azure app services?

Tags: django, azure, websocket, azure-web-app-service, django-channels

I am trying to deploy a web app on azure app service
All the http request work just fine as one would expect
there just one problem none of the websockets work

I am using in memory channels version 2.4.0
and django version 2.2.15

The problem is azure just can not show me proper logs that django shows when running on local server

Answer (score 0):

> What is the proper documentation for using django channels on azure app services?

[Django Channel](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_1.html)

Refer [Deploy Django app with App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/tutorial-django-app-service-postgres?tabs=clone) and [Deploying a Basic Django App using Azure App Services](https://stories.mlh.io/deploying-a-basic-django-app-using-azure-app-services-71ec3b21db08)

> The problem is azure just can not show me proper logs that django shows when running on local server

[image]

Clicking “Show Logs” will show you the different processes happening behind the scenes

Refer [Debug Django Web Application in Azure Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/azureossds/debug-django-web-application-in-azure-web-apps)

Comment: WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ptl/1 [127.0.0.1:50998]
1
1-Station 1
Room :  Line_1_Station_1
WebSocket CONNECT /ptl/1 [127.0.0.1:50998]
WebSocket DISCONNECT /ptl/1 [127.0.0.1:50998]
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /tm/1 [127.0.0.1:51001]
1
Room :  Line_1_Station_1
WebSocket CONNECT /tm/1 [127.0.0.1:51001]

Comment: These kinds of logs I need 
and this answer does not contain information about asgi application

Comment: Is there some way a I could check status of the asgi app

Comment: Refer [deploy with ASGI¶](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/asgi/)

Comment: Sorry but this also doesnt help me because azure app service is an automated service
I want to know how to customize it for websockets

Comment: Have a look at [How to Add Websockets to a Django App](https://jaydenwindle.com/writing/django-websockets-zero-dependencies/) once